# "sudo apt-get update" fails reading broken source

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

While installing GPU enabled TensorFlow on an Ubuntu 14.04 system running on Amazon's EC2, I followed the following steps:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda

tar xvzf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1-ga.tgz
sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

However, on running the command `sudo apt-get update` the following error messages is displayed

```
Err http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main Sources
 Unable to connect to deb.paissad.net:http: [IP: 176.9.119.9 80]
...
...
...
W: Failed to fetch http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer/ubuntu-repo/dists/lucid/main/i18n/Translation-en  Could not resolve 'plex.r.worldssl.net' [IP: 176.9.119.9 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
```

Due to which I am unable to successfully install CUDA and cuDNN.

Could it be possible that my etc/apt/sources/list has been corrupted due to which it is unable to connect to few sources? Can I regain the original sources.list?

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This error doesn't have anything to do with tensorflow actually.

There are other detailed links on how to reset the sources.list in ubuntu.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) for example.

Even easier though just start with an amazon ec2 instance that has already been set up with tensorflow. Alternatively follow one of the many guides online for installing it on EC2 like [here](https://gist.github.com/erikbern/78ba519b97b440e10640) or [here](https://github.com/jasimpson/tensorflow-on-aws)

Comment: I tried to reset the `sources.list` by navigating to `https://repogen.simplylinux.ch.` and generated the sources.list. However on running the `sudo apt-get update` command, the same error is displayed

Comment: The command breaks at `Err http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main Sources
  Unable to connect to deb.paissad.net:http: [IP: 176.9.119.9 80]`

Comment: It's still reading from that broken link which you can disable.

Answer (score 0):

By removing all the broken links from the sources.list file the problem was resolved and sudo apt-get update and sudo-apt-get upgrade works.